# Why is the esxi 6.0 vSphere Web Client is only creating virtual disks on one datastore

Tags: esxi, virtual-disk, vsphere

I have a esxi 6.0 server setup in my lab with 2 physical drives in it.

Datastore1 = 500GB & Datastore2 = 1TB

I am trying to create a new VM with a 2 virtual disks.
The 1st vdisk is 20GB and will exist with the vm machine files on Datastore1
The 2nd vdisk is 500GB and will be on Datastore2.

If I use the "old" vSphere thick client with the above detailed configuration it creates the VM exactly as it should.  However when trying to create it using the vSphere web client the 2nd vdisk is created on Datastore1 even though Datastore2 is selected as the destination.  Likewise if I select to create vdisk1 on Datastore2 and attempt to put vdisk2 on Datastore1 it creates both on Datastore2.

It would seem that it only allowing me to create vdisk's on the same datastore as where the VM machine files are being stored along with the primary vdisk.

I've heard that the 6.0 vSphere web client has some bugs in it, but I can't find anyone else reporting this odd behavior which I find surprising if it were a bug.

Has anyone seen this before or knows if there is a setting I've missed somewhere to allow virtual disks to be created on a different datastore from where the VM machine files & primary vdisk is?

Comment: I see you tagged this vSphere, does that mean, you are also using vSphere.  What "web client" are you talking about exactly?  the Vsphere web client by chance because I am not familiar with a ESXi web client.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes I am referring to the vSphere Thick Client (legacy application) and the vSphere Web Client. It is not managed by vCenter and this is esxi host is using the free license. I've edited the post to indicate vSphere.

Comment: Yes;  I am familiar with using vSphere to manage an ESXi host.  You are talking about the legacy desktop client and the current supported web client.  Unfortunately it simply sounds like a limitation of the web client.  What happens if you create the virtual without the second virtual disk, then after go back into the settings, and add the second virtual disk to the data store you want it to be stored in?  You can also verify you are using the current version of vSphere and/or report the bug directly to VMWare

Comment: Creating the VM with a single Virtual Disk then going back and creating a second virtual disk on Datastore2 still results in it being created on Datastore1.

Comment: I'm running 6.0 not the latest 6.5 but 6.0 is still supported.
If indeed it is an intentional limitation of the Web Client I'd be curious for someone to explain why, its been supported for many years in the Legacy client and is a common configuration in my life.
You mention I can report a bug, but I don't have a support contract, are you sure I have that ability?

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely a bug because the API allows specifying separate locations for each virtual disks and the virtual machine files.

If you connect directly to an ESXi (located at https://<server-hostname-or-ip>/ui) than you are using the ESXi Embedded Host Client. It is distributed as officially supported product and also as a Fling, which is VMware's apps developed by internal engineering teams but not officially supported. The good news is that you could report bugs on the VMware's flings portal at https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client#bugs

By the way I think this is a known issue reported by others. If you go to https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client#comments and search for `I cannot add disk from a different datastore from where a VMis installed` you'll find issue similar to yours.

Considering the issue is fixed you could upgrade your client to the latest Fling. It is distributed as a VIB which you could install on your ESXi.

Comment: So what is the solution to the author's question?

Comment: The answer is on the first line - ESXi Embedded Host Client is only creating virtual disks on one datastore because there is a bug in it. Btw the product for managing ESXi directly (not from vCenter) is called `ESXi Embedded Host Client` and not `vSphere Web Client.`